# React Native: Half pixel border issues on high Pixel Density devices

Tags: ios, react-native, pixel-density

I'm using `0.5px` borders in my React Native app. This works great on most devices but on an `iPhone 6 plus` these borders show up blurry. After reading up on pixel ratios [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pixelratio.html) I've resolved to using something like below.

I wonder if anyone else has been able to successfully use `0.5px` borders on high pixel density devices?

```
borderWidth: PixelRatio.get() >= 3 ? 1 : 0.5
```

Comment: Why not `Stylesheet.hairlineWidth`?

Comment: Wan't aware of such a thing. Thank you! BTW, is the original issue considered a bug or do high density devices not support half pixel lines?

Comment: I think that 0.5px on high density devices simple not align to whole screen pixels. See in source code how hairlineWidth calculated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use [hairlineWidth](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet.html#hairlinewidth) like this:

```
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  elementWithHalfPixelBorder: {
    borderWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
  },
});
```